# How to set the backgroundImage in mxml at run time?

Tags: actionscript-3, embed, mxml

```
public var log_img:Class;

[Embed(source="../images/logo.jpg"）]
```

Which is used this way:

```
<monitor:MonitorDisplay backgroundImage="{ log_img }"/>
```

The above will **Embed** the image into the swf,but I want the image to be loaded from the current website,like

```
<img src="/images/logo.jpg" />
```

How to do this?

I tried this but doesn't work:

```
[source="http://domain.name/images/logo.jpg"]
```

Comment: It depends, how/where do you want to use this image ?

Comment: @soju,I'm using it as a `backgroundImage` attribute in the mxml file.

Answer (score 0):

use the `Loader` class.

a simple example:

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.load(new URLRequest("images/logo.jpg"));
addChild(loader);
```

Comment: Sorry,but the image is used this way:`<monitor:MonitorDisplay backgroundImage="{ log_img }"/>
`

Comment: I take it that the monitor:MonitorDisplay is a class that loads a backgroundImage - it's not a standard Flex class is it? Then that MonitorDisplay class should be able to load that image, or you should make it use the Loader in there. Did you write that MonitorDisplay class yourself?

Answer (score 0):

I you want to load dynamically an image, you should look at the [Loader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html) class.

For example :

```
var imageLoader : Loader = new Loader();
imageLoader.load(new URLRequest("http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3575/3293166516_de2cd751fc.jpg"));
addChild(imageLoader);
```

Comment: mmhhh I don't understand your issue... If it's in the mxml file, it's directly available in your code. Can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: I can't get the image by `<monitor:MonitorDisplay backgroundImage="http://domain.name/images/logo.jpg"/>`